# Instagram API Permission declined - website access

Tags: php, instagram-api

I have my app reviewed and declined for permissions to use Instagram API. Their feedback is:

> **General issues:**
>
> We are unable to access your website. Please make sure
>   to provide a valid URL and any login credentials required to view your
>   site.

Both my websites - for app and privacy policy - are up and working. This is my 2nd time being reviewed for this app. I've already tried adding some more stuff to the app website, still - declined.

My question is - which website they're talking about? The one is called "*Website URL*" in *Manage Client* section or "*Privacy Policy URL*" or even some other one I don't know about?

These are the urls I've provided them:

> **Website URL:** http://94.176.238.81/ingroup.html
>
> **Privacy Policy URL:** https://docs.google.com/document/d/1c5cpT2PleLv3vII517fGh0eASWSMsgrnauUYzMgWE-k/pub

The only thing I can think of is that I gave them IP address and not domain name. Do I really have to buy some random domain for my IP website to get accepted? Or will something like *tinyurl.com/...* work? Or is it something else completely?

Comment: I think you should ask Instragram.

Comment: @Halcyon Yes, I did ask them too, but it was 2 days ago and I got no answer yet, so I'm asking you as well. :)

Comment: Maybe they want a real domain name, not an IP address.

Comment: They answered me after 4 days:
_Your site gives out Access Tokens which is not in guidelines with our policies. We would like those developers to come and submit on our developer site rather than using yours._
I still don't know how can I solve this, so I'll use some plugin for getting access token instead - like: http://instagram.pixelunion.net/